# How is term structure of interest rate reflected in Vasicek?

Tags: fixed-income

I have been scratching my head over this question, but could not find out an answer. Can anyone explain how is term structure reflected from a short rate model?

Specifically, if we have a stochastic differential equation for dR(t). It is possible calculate the one year rate, two year rate three year rate etc from the integrals $\int_o^tR(t)dt$. However, how do we make sure that the two year rate is bigger than the one year rate?

Comment: you want to fit a term-structure ?

Comment: I was thinking about the setup and am wondering how a short rate model makes sure that the two year rate is bigger than the one year rate?

Comment: I think you want your short rate model to be able to fit an inverted curve as well since it can happen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_curve#/media/File:GBP_yield_curve_09_02_2005.JPG